# One Search Bar, Multiple Buttons

Tags: html

Out of curiosity, is there such a thing as one searchbar, with multiple buttons, each button a different pathway/action, but with the search results unaffected?

Here is what I think the code would be like:

```
<form action = 'POST'>
  <input type: 'text' name: 'searchbar'>
  <input type: 'submit' name: 'search'>
  <input type: 'submit' name: 'add'>
  <input type: 'submit' name: 'delete'>
</form>
```

If there is such a concept, can you please tell me what do I do to accomplish? If not, is there an alternative way?

Comment: Yes, such a thing could work. You'd just run different conditional server-side logic based on the `name` attribute you're sending across in `POST`. Exactly how you do that depends on your server-side programming language(s). Your HTML should have equals signs though, not colons.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```js
$("#myForm [name=action1]").click(function(){
  $.post(url1, data, function (data, status) {
  });
});

$("#myForm [name=action2]").click(function(){
  $.get(url2, data, function (data, status) {
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <button name="action1">Action 1</button>
  <button name="action2">Action 2</button>
</form>
```